# smbclient -c with ls -l option

Tags: linux, windows, shell, remote-server

i am trying to get folder lists from remote server, and it is not possible to mount remote server into my local computer (because of the permission issue).

i used

```
smbclient "//165.186.89.21/DeptDQ_141Q_FOTA" "--user=myid" -c 'ls;'
```

to get lists of the folder.
and the result was success.

but, actually i want to use `ls -l` with the above the command line
and when i try to get results using the line

```
smbclient "//165.186.89.21/DeptDQ_141Q_FOTA" "--user=LGE\final.lee" -c 'ls -l;'
```

it returns

```
NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE listing \-l

            64000 blocks of size 16777216. 6503 blocks available
```

...
how should i use smbclient operator with ls -l option?
please help me!

Comment: This is a usage question, not a programming question. Thus, it would be better placed on SuperUser rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`smbclient ls` does not run a native `ls` command, but rather invokes built-in functionality. As such, it does not support the usual options which a native, POSIX-compliant `ls` command would provide.

Thus, you cannot do this.

If your goal is to read metadata, consider trying the `smbclient stat [filename]` subcommand instead (if your server supports UNIX extensions), or `smbclient allinfo [filename]` (otherwise).

Comment: windows Server doesn't support UNIX CIFS calls.you cant use  stat for windows server

Comment: @yes, true. The OP didn't specify Windows Server in the question, and accepted this answer, indicating that it solved their problem. That said, I've amended the answer to also specify `smbclient allinfo`.

Comment: OP is asking similar command as ls-l(ie permission, username, size, month, date, time, filename) which is not possible using smbclient. allinfo is not similar to ls-l

Comment: @yes, the fact that the OP is passing a single filename (and that they accepted this answer) means they clearly *don't* want to get a full listing, but metadata about that named file. If you have a question that's different from theirs (when the body is taken into account), that's a separate question and should be asked as such (though somewhere it's on-topic, as opposed to here). (I'd also agree that an edit to the title to make it better reflect their actual question may be called for).