# Create link in network share

Tags: symlink, samba, network-share

I need to create symbolic link in linux network share using smbclient commands.
I tried below commands and no luck.

```
smbclient ${share} mfsymlinks xxx/y.html y.html
smbclient ${share} ln -s xxx/y.html y.html
smbclient ${share} symlink xxx/y.html y.html
```

Can anyone let me know how to create a link in network share.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you should use the `-c` parameter of *smbclient* in order to issue a file operation [see example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354920/smbclient-c-with-ls-l-option).
- As for specifically linking, I see in the manual that you can create unix type links only if your server supports [unix extensions](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#UNIXEXTENSIONS) (it means that *smb.conf* file of the samba server specifies `unix extensions = yes`). Then, you could issue the operation `link target linkname`: Search for "link" in [smbclient manual](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbclient.1.html)

Comment: I have used the -c option in all the commands, forgot to include in question.
I will check the next option.

Comment: BTW: unix extensions are implemented only for SMB version 1.0 (mount option "vers=1.0") which shouldn't be used anymore. So I guess links shouldn't be considered with Samba at all.